# Собрать значения и вернуть .map() или .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, что-то никак не соображу: есть верстка из 4 элементов, в котором есть в поле div число (наценка).
Нужно собрать эти числа, к каждому прибавить некую сумму (константу) и вернуть обратно но в другое поле. Я пробовал так:

```
var classes = $("#tkans_block ul li .pricegroup_markup").map(function(indx, element){
        $(element).text(parseInt($(element).text().replace(/\s/g, ''))+parseInt(current_price));
    });
```

Но у меня при таком раскладе при повторном срабатывании события он уже прибавляет те суммы, что перед этим вернулись в поля, поэтому я вынес саму наценку в другое поле но теперь во все поля возвращается только результат последней итерации.
Вот разметка:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="msbabrics_pricegroup active">
    <div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">0.00</div>
    <div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_1"><span>14790</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</li>
<li class="msbabrics_pricegroup">
    <div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">1220.00</div>
    <div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_2"><span>14790</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</li>
<li class="msbabrics_pricegroup">
    <div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">2800.00</div>
    <div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_3"><span>14790</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</li>
<li class="msbabrics_pricegroup"><div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">4020.00</div>
    <div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_4"><span>14790</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</li>
```

То есть кратко: нужно собрать значения из полей `<div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">...</div>` прибавить к каждому числу например 10 000 и вернуть результат операции в поле span `<div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_4"><span>...</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.pr_gr_markup_price').each(function(){
  var price = +$(this).text(),
      step = 1000;
  $(this).siblings('.pricegroup_markup').children('span').text((price+step).toFixed(2));
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="msbabrics_pricegroup active">
    <div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">0.00</div>
    <div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_1"><span>14790</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</li>
<li class="msbabrics_pricegroup">
    <div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">1220.00</div>
    <div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_2"><span>14790</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</li>
<li class="msbabrics_pricegroup">
    <div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">2800.00</div>
    <div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_3"><span>14790</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</li>
<li class="msbabrics_pricegroup"><div class="hide pr_gr_markup_price">4020.00</div>
    <div class="pricegroup_markup prgr_price_4"><span>14790</span> <i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: toFixed(2) - это для двух нулей послу точки

Comment: Спасибо большое!